# Why my for loop doesn't increment the var i? (UPDATED)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

UPDATE:
the before-title is wrong, the foor loop is ok (probably).
The problem is that I can't make a reference to the product itself. At the last if (if(notItsPlace)) it's not the productArr[i].parentNode I have to use but the product-name, but I need to sort the products themselves. So the new question is:

**How to make a reference to an element that's two levels up?**

---

Hi everyone,
I'm new in JavaScript and have a quick question:
In my code below the foor loop does not increment the var i but stucks in an infinite loop.
I'm sure something is out of order but can't figure it out what.

The task is to place the product items in alphabetical order (and many other), and the products in this case are not coming from a database but it's written in the HTML (I know).
Can't edit the HTML and would not like to use JQuery.

Thank you in advance!

```js
var sortingSel = document.querySelector(".order");
var product = document.querySelectorAll("div[class='product']");
var productArr = Array.from(product);

sortingSel.onchange = function(){

    var sortingOpt = parseInt(sortingSel.options[sortingSel.selectedIndex].value);

    var notItsPlace;
    var switchPlace = true;

    switch(sortingOpt){
        
        case 2:

            while (switchPlace){

                switchPlace = false;

                for (var i = 0; i < (productArr.length -1); i++){
                    console.log("i = " + i);

                    notItsPlace = false;
                            
                    if (productArr[i].querySelector(".product-name").innerText.toLowerCase() > productArr[i + 1].querySelector(".product-name").innerText.toLowerCase()){

                        notItsPlace = true;
                        break;
                    } 
                }

                if (notItsPlace){
                    productArr[i].parentNode.insertBefore(productArr[i + 1], productArr[i]);
                    
                    switchPlace = true;
                } 
            }

            break;
            default:
                console.log("def");
    }
}
```

```html
 <select style="padding: 10px;" class="order">
                        <option value="0">case 0</option>
                        <option value="1">case 1</option>
                        <option value="2">case 2</option>
                        <option value="3">case 3</option>
</select>


<div class="products">
                <div class="product">
                    <span class="image-container">
                        <img src="">
                    </span>
                    <div class="product-data" data-identifier="6">
                        <div class="product-name">CNAME</div>
                        <div class="product-price">PRICE</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="product">
                    <span class="image-container">
                        <img src="">
                    </span>
                    <div class="product-data" data-identifier="6">
                        <div class="product-name">ANAME</div>
                        <div class="product-price">PRICE</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="product">
                    <span class="image-container">
                        <img src="">
                    </span>
                    <div class="product-data" data-identifier="6">
                        <div class="product-name">BNAME</div>
                        <div class="product-price">PRICE</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to be a [mcve]

Comment: Tried my best, snippet is done. Is this what you've asked for or not exactly?

Comment: Please don't change the question after someone has taken the time to submit an answer.

Comment: Right, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to use another sorting method, in which all the products are first collected, then sorted and then inserted into the layout.

There used method js for right sorting 'String' [localeCompare](https://javascript.info/string#correct-comparisons) and a [reduce](https://javascript.info/array-methods#reduce-reduceright) for the layout assembly.

```js
var sortingSel = document.querySelector(".order");
var product = document.querySelectorAll("div[class='product']");
var productList = document.querySelector('.products');
var productArr = Array.from(product);

sortingSel.onchange = function(){
 
  var sortingOpt = parseInt(sortingSel.options[sortingSel.selectedIndex].value);
  
  newProductArr = productArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    const elemA = a.querySelector(".product-name").innerText;
    const elemB = b.querySelector(".product-name").innerText;
    
    if (sortingOpt === 2) {
      return elemA.localeCompare(elemB);
    } else {
      return elemB.localeCompare(elemA)
    }
  });
  
  newProductListArr = newProductArr.reduce(function(acc, elem) {
    return acc + elem.innerHTML;
  }, '');
  
  productList.innerHTML = newProductListArr;
}
```

```html
<select style="padding: 10px;" class="order">
                        <option value="0">case 0</option>
                        <option value="1">case 1</option>
                        <option value="2">case 2</option>
                        <option value="3">case 3</option>
</select>


<div class="products">
                <div class="product">
                    <span class="image-container">
                        <img src="">
                    </span>
                    <div class="product-data" data-identifier="6">
                        <div class="product-name">CNAME</div>
                        <div class="product-price">PRICE</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="product">
                    <span class="image-container">
                        <img src="">
                    </span>
                    <div class="product-data" data-identifier="6">
                        <div class="product-name">ANAME</div>
                        <div class="product-price">PRICE</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="product">
                    <span class="image-container">
                        <img src="">
                    </span>
                    <div class="product-data" data-identifier="6">
                        <div class="product-name">BNAME</div>
                        <div class="product-price">PRICE</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I'll try it

Comment: It works well, thanks :) The problem is the CSS's gone crazy because every product had its own container div and with your code this div has gone, so the big container (.products) contains the parameters each and every product "nude", like img, name div etc.

Comment: changed the "reduce" part to this less elegant one:  productList.innerHTML = "";
    
    for (let pr of newProductArr){
        productList.innerHTML += pr.outerHTML;
    };